# PHP interpreter not loading with netbeans error

Tags: codeigniter, netbeans

I am having trouble installing the Codeigniter support for Netbeans IDE 7.3.l from the following page.

```
https://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/Home
```

I have codeigniter214 and the zip pointed to the same zip that's on the CI download page.

I've gotten to the point where it should show the core and the reactor zips but I'm not even sure that looks right because when I go to create a new CI project and select codeigniter214 for the base file when I select the CI framework it says PHP interpreter must be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since asking this question I have come to find out that the problem is/was that in netbeans the php interpreter was not set. The setting was empty.

The solution to my original question is:

- go into the php settings inside of netbeans
- check to see if the value for the PHP 5 Interpreter field drop down
  is empty.

If it is empty:

- click "browse" and locate the copy of php.exe inside the xampp folder
- select the file to set it as the interpreter
- save

Comment: example of before/after?

Comment: One thing to add, happened to me that I needed to install Java plugin alongside with CodeIgniter Framework plugin. Setting up PHP interpreter throw a Java error, and lucky guess was that plugin was a must.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me:
netbeans does problems sometimes but the tricky solution is that just browse for the interpreter and then export your general settings only into a zip file, then restart netbeans and import that zip file and restart netbeans once again and the problem solved.